# Android Studio - java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application

Tags: android, android-studio, filenotfoundexception, build.gradle, android-multidex

I am working on a project in eclipse, but after sometime it giving me error like `"Unable to execute dex: method ID not in" as single DEX file having 65k method limitations.`

To overcome the issue I come into the picture of `Gradle plugin v0.14.0 for Android adds support for Multi-Dex.` So I moved to **Android Studio.**

I have updated SDK and exported project from eclipse as per [Migrating from Eclipse.](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html)

Now I have project structure required in Android Studio.Their is dependency of project on ABS, Google Play Service lib and android multidex support lib. I have added these libraries to my project folder named "libraries".

Project Gradle file looks something below:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.1'
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
compile project(':libraries:ABS')
compile project(':libraries:GooglePlayServiceLib')


compile (project(':libraries:android-support-multidex')) {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}


  compile "com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0"


}


android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false


   }


sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }


    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')


    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}


}

afterEvaluate {
tasks.matching {
    it.name.startsWith('dex')
}.each { dx ->
    if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
        dx.additionalParameters = ['--multi-dex']
    } else {
        dx.additionalParameters += '--multi-dex'
    }
}
}
```

When I clean and build project it builds successfully. But when I run project as android application giving me following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.example-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

I am thinking that application is not compiling AndroidManifest.xml OR I am something missing ?
Any help is going to be appreciated. :)

Comment: You're probably better off just generating a new project and copying everything to that as recently the Android Studio gradle stuff drastically changed. First the SDK was included in AS, now the whole folder can't contain any non-AS external files.

Comment: So there is no other option to overcome this issue? As my project allready on SVN, I dont want to remove and add again. If this will be the end of the story then Android Studio should seriously work on this issue.

Comment: Well, this is primarily my opinion but you should be using a modern versioning system anyway, like Git. You also shouldn't include IDE specific files in your versioning. Migrating isn't as hard as it seems though. Just create a new, empty and working project. Then copy paste in your resources and source files. AS will pretty much automatically handle everything else, though you'll probably have to copy the activity definitions from your old AndroidManifest.xml